# Identities like $4+5+6=7+8$ and $10^2+11^2+12^2=13^2+14^2$ and so on...

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, computational-mathematics

The identities

$1+2=3$
$4+5+6=7+8$
$3^2+4^2=5^2$
$10^2+11^2+12^2=13^2+14^2$
$21^2+22^2+23^2+24^2=25^2+26^2+27^2$

are examples of *consecutive identities*. Are there any consecutive identities except $3^3+4^3+5^3=6^3$ for exponents greater than $2?$

The identities should be built upon additions only.

---

For consecutive identities 
$m^k+\cdots+(m+n-1)^k=(m+n)^k+\cdots+(m+2n-2)^k$ 
there is a gap $\Delta^k$ between last number in one identity sequence to the first number in the next possible consecutive identity for k=1 and for k=2: $\Delta^1=1$ and $\Delta^2=2n+3,\;n=1,2,\dots$ :

$1+2=3$
$4+5+6=7+8$
$9+10+11+12=13+14+15$
$16+17+18+19+20=21+22+23+24$

$1=4-3=9-8=16-15 \dots$

$3^2+4^2=5^2$
$10^2+11^2+12^2=13^2+14^2$
$21^2+22^2+23^2+24^2=25^2+26^2+27^2$
$36^2+37^2+38^2+39^2+40^2=41^2+42^2+43^2+44^2$

$10-5=2\cdot 1+3$
$21-14=2\cdot 2+3$
$36-27=2\cdot 3+3$

I don't think there is a straight continuation for $k>2$, but there might be  consecutive identities of a slightly different kind, e.g:

$(1)\quad m^k+\cdots+(m+n-1)^k=(m+n)^k+\cdots+(m+2n-i)^k$, where $i>2?$

---

Examination of $(1)$ for $k=3$ and $1\leq m,n,i\leq 5000$ only yield the solution $3^3+4^3+5^3=6^3$.

Comment: The counter-examples to Euler's conjecture are nice ones using fourth powers and powers with even larger exponents.

Comment: @Peter: which is that?

Comment: Look here for some amazing equations : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_sum_of_powers_conjecture

Comment: @Lehs ; may be this is interesting for you: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2408850/how-to-prove-that-12-3-456-78-ad-infinitum

Comment: Suppose that $S_k(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n i^k$ is the sum of all the $k$th powers up to $n$. (Note that there's an explicit polynomial expression for $S_k$ as a $(k+1)$-th degree polynomial in $n$). Then any sum of consecutive powers is of the form $S_k(n)-S_k(m)$; you're essentially asking about solutions of $S_k(n)-S_k(m) = S_k(p)-S_k(q)$ (or, equivalently, $S_k(n)+S_k(q) = S_k(m)+S_k(p)$. This should at least make searching (e.g. in the $k=3$ case) much easier; checking all cases with $m,n,p,q\lt 10^6$, say, should be comfortably within a day of CPU time.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Also I'd add Lehs that $S_k(n)$ can be express explicitly in terms of Bernoulli polynomials, which there are a lot of algorithms to calculate or if you're using a CAS likely a built in function for.

Answer (score 6):

MORE EDIT. For cubes, it reduces to the problem of finding three triangular numbers whose squares are in arithmetic progression. Recalling that $$1^3+2^3+\cdots+r^3=\left({r(r+1)\over2}\right)^2=T_r^2$$ an equation of the form $$(m+1)^3+(m+2)^3+\cdots+(m+n)^3=(m+n+1)^3+(m+n+2)^3+\cdots+(m+n+k)^3$$ becomes $$T_{m+n}^2-T_m^2=T_{m+n+k}^2-T_{m+n}^2$$ which says the squares of $T_m$, $T_{m+n}$, and $T_{m+n+k}$ are in arithmetic progression.

E.g., we have $T_2=3$, $T_5=15$, $T_6=21$, and the squares $9,225,441$ are in arithmetic progression, and this corresponds to $3^3+4^3+5^3=6^3$. Whether there are any more examples, I do not know.

Everything below relates to a misunderstanding of the question, and can safely be ignored.

There are (infinitely) many examples of consecutive cubes summing to a cube. About 20 are listed [here](https://benvitalenum3ers.wordpress.com/2014/08/06/when-sum-of-cubes-equals-a-cube/), starting with
$$11^3+12^3+13^3+14^3=20^3$$ 
$$3^3+\cdots22^3=40^3$$ 
$$15^3+\cdots+34^3=70^3$$ 
An answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/199297/sum-of-consecutive-cubes) links to Dave Rusin's "known math" pages, but Rusin's site seems to have vanished from the web. Much of what Rusin had for the problem of sum of consecutive cubes a cube is reproduced [here](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath147.htm).

EDIT: Discussion of related questions at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53134/what-sums-of-equal-powers-of-consecutive-natural-numbers-are-powers-of-the-same).

Comment: However those are **not** consequtive identities in the sense put forth in the question.

Comment: @sky, yes, I missed that the right side was meant to start where the left side ended.

Comment: Here's a close one: $$4^3+5^3+\dots+28^3 = 30^3+31^3+\dots+34^3$$

Answer (score 3):

The [formula for the sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_(algebra)#Sum_of_cubes_of_numbers_in_arithmetic_progression) of $n$ cubes of numbers in arithmetic progression $d$ is given by,

$$\begin{align}F(d,a,n)
&=a^3+(a+d)^3+(a+2d)^3+\cdots+(a+dn-d)^3\\
&= (n/4)(2a-d+dn)(2a^2-2ad+2adn-d^2n+d^2n^2)\end{align}$$

Consecutive numbers is just the special case $d=1$ and we have the well-known,

$$3^3+4^3+5^3 = 6^3$$

A computer search within a reasonable radius doesn't yield other solutions, even if the RHS is a sum of cubes. But if we allow more general $d$, then for arithmetic progression $d=5$ we also have the nice,

$$47^3 + \color{blue}{52}^3 + 57^3 + \color{blue}{62}^3 + 67^3 + \color{blue}{72}^3 + 77^3 + \color{blue}{82}^3 = 87^3 + \color{blue}{92}^3 + 97^3$$

Answer (score 2):

$$n^2+(n+1)^2+...+(n+k)^2=(n+k+1)^2+...+(n+2k)^2$$

Solutions are easy. $n=(2k+1)k$